# How to redirect to 403 Forbidden in htaccess when trying to upload audio files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am looking for a little code I can use in my htaccess to prevent audio and video uploads in my website and redirect automatically to 403 Forbidden. I spent this weekend looking everywhere and found similar fragments of codes in my wp-content's htaccess but my skills with htaccess are pretty short and I could not make it work. I am looking for something simple , just denying audio and video uploads for everybody and auto redirecting to the 403 Forbidden default page, non a personalied 403 Forbidden.

Comment: You must rewrite whatever the upload url is and use the [`F`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f) flag, e.g. `RewriteRule ^path/to/upload$ - [F]`

Comment: It seems deny all upload attepts targeting upload directory... Now I have a new idea... I'll try...!!!